# Getting "Couldn't find Item without an ID" when trying to render to a view.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am new to programming, 12 weeks in to  learning Ruby on Rails, and this SHOULD be an easy problem, but  its not. I have a feature spec (I'm using Capybara and RSpec) I'm running on a simple "To do" list application. I want to render @item to items#show and the test keeps failing:

```
Failures:

  1) User creates ITEM Successfully
     Failure/Error: expect( page ).to have_content('washcar')
       expected to find text "washcar" in "Your new ITEM was saved. Your new ITEM was saved."
     # ./spec/features/user_creates_item.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the show view:

```
<p><b><%= @item.body %></b></p>
```

Okay, simple so far. Here is the item controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end



  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.save
    redirect_to @item, notice: 'Your new ITEM was saved.'
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end


  def index
  end  

private

   def item_params
     params.require(:item).permit(:body)
   end
 end
```

Here is the spec:

```
require 'rails_helper' 

feature 'User creates ITEM' do
  scenario 'Successfully' do
    visit new_item_path
    fill_in 'Body', with:'washcar'
    click_button 'Save' 

    expect( page ).to have_content('Your new ITEM was saved')    
    expect( page ).to have_content('washcar')
  end  
end
```

Here is items#new

```
<h1>Items#new</h1>

<%= form_for Item.new do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :body, placeholder: 'Body' %> 
   <%= form.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

and here is the item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

  scope :unfinished, -> { where('done' => false) }
  scope :unfinished_and_recent, -> { unfinished.where("created_at > ?", Time.now-7.days) }
  scope :finished, -> { where('done' => true) }

  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :list, presence: true
 end
```

My understanding is: on item#new, the test provides the body for the item "washcar' and form.submit 'Save' sends a request to the router, which matches the request to the ItemsController create method. There, the private method item_params passes body and item info to Item.new, which is then assigned to @item. @item.save saves the item to the db, and redirect_to @item redirects to the show method. params passes the item saved in the database to Item.find, which is then assigned to @item. items#show is then supposed to render @item.body to the view, but it looks like it doesn't. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a validation error as you have `validate :list, presence: true` in your model and you didn't specify list in view. Can you recheck?